# How do I push and pop the matrix stack in LibGDX

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm having a hard time finding the equivalent of the very basic OpenGL functionality `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` in LibGDX.

I have rendered my scene and I would like to render an overlay on top of the scene but I would like to do it in screen coordinates so I want to push the modelview matrix and load identity.

In essence I would like to perform the equivalent of:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

... stuff ...

glPopMatrix();
```

But for the life of me, I cannot find a single mention of push or pop in the LibGDX documentation nor in the parts of source code that I have looked at.

Am I missing something? Is there some other preferred way of achieving this?

#### Edit:

What I want to achieve is a fade to black while I load the next level and then fade in. I do this by rendering a black rectangle over the display with alpha. None of that is a problem, I just want to have a fixed, known coordinate system independent of the current world transform to render this rectangle in.

Comment: I can't believe people still using that matrix stacks ancient stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods are part of the fixed render pipe of OpenGL ES 1. Support for OpenGL ES 1 has been removed since libGDX version 1.0.0. Only the programmable render pipe op OpenGL ES 2 and up is supported. If you really want to use such old methods then you could use an older version of libGDX.

The question "how to render a HUD overlay?" is too broad to explain here. But for basic methods (like rendering a HUD overlay) libGDX abstracts away the need of using any gl methods at all. You might want to have a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki), which includes some basic [examples](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game). And follow a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/user/dermetfan) (although tutorials tend to get outdated of time, so be aware of that).

But assuming you are using SpriteBatch, then use `batch.setProjectionMatrix()`

Comment: I know how to render a HUD, I just want to have a fixed coordinate system to render it to.

Comment: In that case you `Stage` viewport should take care of it. Without seeing any code it is impossible to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: See the edit on the main question. Using the scene2d ui framework for this is overkill. (I have not yet written the code, I'm just trying to figure out how to get the desired transform matrixes in place).

Comment: As said, without seeing code it's just guessing. But assuming you are using SpriteBatch, then use `batch.setProjectionMatrix()`.

Comment: @Emily L. I upvote for that answer, if you consider that helped the solution of your problem might consider upvote thanks